# Toolbar contents not showing in Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am having a few troubles while developing an Android app that contains a Toolbar (using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`). While the application title and the Settings overflow displays correctly on all other Android versions (I have checked using API 10 and API 17), the contents don't seem to display at all in Android 6.0. This is the case on both my main phone (LG G4) and  Android 6.0 emulators I am using.

The menu contents I am using are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Settings, in the overflow. -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />
</menu>
```

and the code that I am using to inflate the menu is:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_home, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }
```

I am using custom styles, but these are derived from the AppCompat theme meaning that they should be properly working.

Here are some screenshots to illustrate the problem:
[in Marshmallow:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij8xw.png)

[in JellyBean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7VD4.png)

I have never seen this problem before - I tried to Google it, but nothing came up in my search. Is this some weird bug in Android 6?

Many thanks for your help!

-- Solved -- it was just that the ID was missing in the Marshmallow version of the layout file. Many thanks for all of the help!

Comment: Can you post your layout res?

Comment: I will do this as soon as I can (it's on a computer I cannot access at the moment)